# How to remove all of the contents of a string except the first character?

Tags: stata

I have a data set with first name, middle name, and last name. I'm going to merge it with another data set matching on the same variables. 
In one data set the variable `mi` looks like:

```
Lowell
Ann
Carl
A
Fran
Allen
```

And I want it to look like:

```
L
A
C
A
F
A
```

I tried this:

```
gen mi2 = substr(mi, 2, length(mi))
```

but this does the opposite of what I want but it's the closest that I've been able to do. I know this is probably a really easy problem but I'm stumped at the moment.

Comment: On a different note, reducing to one character will make merges harder. Your own example shows that `A` is now highly ambiguous.

Comment: @NickCox I guess I forgot to add that I'm also merging on date of birth. The data is unique at the first name, middle name, last name, dob level. Ideally I would have a unique ID but data doesn't always come the way you want it to :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track with `substr`. See the example below:

```
clear

input str10 mi
Lowell
Ann
Carl
A
Fran
Allen
end

gen mi2 = substr(mi,1,1)
list, sep(0)

     +--------------+
     |     mi   mi2 |
     |--------------|
  1. | Lowell     L |
  2. |    Ann     A |
  3. |   Carl     C |
  4. |      A     A |
  5. |   Fran     F |
  6. |  Allen     A |
     +--------------+
```

The second and third arguments to `substr` are the starting position and number of characters respectively. In this case, you want to start at the first character, and take one character, so `substr(mi, 1, 1)` is what you need.

Comment: Of course! The help file to `substr` always confuses me. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Note that `gen str1 mi1 = mi` is a brute force alternative. You insist on `str1` as storage type, so there is only room for one character.

Comment: That's true, and equally valid, but I can't help but think that feels like a crude method.

Comment: If you think of the syntax as "I want one character (which I know will be the first)" it's no less awkward than using `substr()`. All in the mind....